# Using the chain rule to find second order partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, chain-rule

Given the application $u(r,\phi):=v(r\cos\phi, r\sin \phi)$ I need to find by the chain rule an expression for $\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}$ in terms of second partial derivatives of $u.$ I found first the Jacobian matrix based on the transformation function $(r,\phi)\rightarrow (x,y)=(r\cos \phi, r \sin \phi).$ Since this application is not a function, I do not know if one has to go through the Hessian matrix to find the second partial derivatives. Can you provide me some support or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: Where do $x,y$ feature in all this?

Comment: $(x,y)$ is represented by polar coordinates. I need to thus represent the two second order partial derivatives in terms of partial derivatives of $u$ and the polar coordinates.

Comment: You will confuse yourself and everyone else unless you write  something sensible like "$u(r,\phi)=v(x,y)$ where $x=r\cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\phi$". The result  is in every book: what is the problem?

Comment: @user996159  Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since you want an expression of the second order partial derivatives of $u$, begin by finding what *they* are in terms of the p.d. of $v$ and the derivatives of $x$ and $y$.

**Reason:** the first and second order partial derivatives of $x, y$ with respect to $r, \phi$ are much easier to find than the inverse, and trigonometric identities may be useable.$$\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}=\cos\phi~, \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}=-r\sin\phi~, \dfrac{\partial^2 x}{\partial r~^2}=0~,\textit{et cetera}\ldots$$